# How to catch error from sweet alert ajax function?

Tags: php, json, ajax, sweetalert

after several searches I cannot find a solution for my problems on sweet alert.
I need to show the user a dedicated error message when ajax send a specific message.

my function:

```
function fadd() {    
      Swal.fire({
title: 'do you want to save?',
icon: 'question',
showCancelButton: true,
confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
confirmButtonText: 'Si',
cancelButtonText: 'No'
}).then((result) => {
if (result.value) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxfile.php",
success: function(){ 
                  console.log(response['abc']);
                   }

})
  }
})
}
```

on ajax (ajaxfile.php) i have:

```
if($sqlcr->num_rows === 0) {
    $insql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (item) VALUES('".$cont."','".$tp."','".$usercode."')");
mysql_query($insql);    

 return response(json_encode(array("abc"=>'ok')));
} 
else {
    return response(json_encode(array("abc"=>'failed')));
}
}
```

the problem is that from the function i cannot catch the json message "failed"...

i found some example codes on the web but the missing part is the ajax configuration file, maybe something wrong there...

any help on this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It 's all about response headers. If a request fails, you usually do not return a HTTP 200 OK, because the response should not be OK if something went wrong. Here 's a short example how to use HTTP headers for expressing, that something went wrong.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Marcel;

$failure = true;

// everything is fine - send a http 200
if ($failure === false) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode([ 'test' => 'ok' ]);
    exit();
}

if ($failure === true) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 422 Unprocessable Entity');
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode([ 'test' => 'not ok' ]);
    exit();
}
```

You can find a complete list of http status codes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Since we have a status code in the response, we can handle this with your jQuery snippet, because everything what is not in the 200 range is not okay, we can use the `error` function of jQuery 's async request.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajaxfile.php',
    success: (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: (request, status, error) => {
        console.log(request);
    }
});
```

Because the http status codes jQuery knows when an error was thrown.

Comment: A small hint: Do not use mysql_* functions anymore. They are outdated since years and will not work with current PHP versions.